# Simulate a triggered(QAction *) in a menu

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Im developing an application that uses voice to simulate some actions: drag and drop, select item, click buttons,etc.
Now i have a menu that i need to simulate is clicked or triggered.

```
for linktype in globals.linkTypes.keys():
                    menu.addAction(linktype)
                menu.connect(menu, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered(QAction *)"), self.__setLinkType)
                menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
```

When i say the name of one linktype in the menu i need that it generates the triggered signal.
HOw can i emit it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QMenu::addAction(const QString&)` returns the created `QAction`, just call `trigger()` on it.

```
action = menu.addAction(linktype)
...
action.trigger();
```

Comment: I can do the same on python? What is the syntax? Sorry im newbie!

Comment: @karensantana I have no idea what your example code is supposed to do, but if you want to trigger a `QAction`, just call it's `trigger()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what i was looking for the whole night!